# Get a value from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

If I have a numpy matrix:

```
>>> S
matrix([[ 0.66581073+0.00033919j],
        [ 0.81568896-0.03291265j],
        [ 0.99884785+0.00045446j]])
```

How do I get an element, without the `matrix` wrapper?

If I try:

```
>>> S[0]
```

I get:

```
matrix([[ 0.66581073+0.00033919j]])
```

whereas what I want is:

```
0.66581073+0.00033919j
```

I have had a look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)  and can't find a function/operator to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> I = np.matrix([[ 0.66581073+0.00033919j],
        [ 0.81568896-0.03291265j],
        [ 0.99884785+0.00045446j]])
>>> 
>>> I[0, 0]
(0.66581073000000002+0.00033919000000000001j)
```

Comment: To complete @jamylak answer: when you do `S[0]`, you're actually accessing the first *row* of your matrix, which is itself a matrix. You want to access the first element of the first row, therefore `S[0,0]` (that is, first row, first column)